# Run macro in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub MisRec()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
        Cells.Find(What:="abc", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, "A2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Next ws
End Sub
```

This is the code I have now which is not working fine for me.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: want to run this code in all worksheets in the workbook

Comment: Select and delete rows between ActiveCell row and row 2 in all sheets (ActiveCell is dynamic in each Worksheet)

Comment: `Cells.Find` will always apply to the activesheet, not `ws`

Comment: And the `ActiveCell` would always be in the last sheet searched. It's an Application-level property, not a worksheet property. So, it's **not** *dynamic in each worksheet*, as you thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more explicit about where you're searching, and also you should test that something was found before proceeding:

```
Sub MisRec()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, f As Range
    For Each ws In Worksheets
            Set f = ws.Cells.Find(What:="abc", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not f Is Nothing then
                ws.Range(f.Offset(-2, 0), ws.Range("A2")).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I wanted to modify this and add more functions

Comment: What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: From ActiveCell I want to go down till the cells with values and then go two rows down and delete all rows below there may be 500

Comment: If Not f Is Nothing Then
                        ws.Range(f.Offset(-2, 0), ws.Range("A2")).EntireRow.Delete &
                        wsRange(f, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                        ws.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0), 
    ws.Range("A500")).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
        Next ws
    End Sub

Comment: this code runs just for one sheet but not all sheets - it stops in the second sheet

Comment: Either update your question above, or (better) post a new question explaining what you're trying to do, and exactly what problem you have with your current code.